# subcircuits powering (predetermined time delay, ~8 seconds)

Tags: power, timing, power-sequencing

In order to control inrush current, and also to make sure some subcircuits and modules are OK on startup, I need a predetermined time delay between delivering power to these subcircuits. (Automatic power up, without switch/buttons, delayed power delivery)

My desired procedure is :

1. When the main power is supplied, sub-circuit-A is powered, others are not.
2. After 8-12 seconds, sub-circuit-B is powered.
3. After 1-3 second, sub-circuit-A is turned off.
4. After 1-3 second, sub-circuit-B is turned off.

As the time ranges indicate, timing accuracy is the least concern here. Also if it requires 2 or 3 timer ICs it's ok.
These two circuits (A and B) draw 100mA each, supply is 12 V DC.

I found circuits and tutorials on using 555 IC, but can't figure a way to use them to result in my demand.(i.e I need both A and B to be turned off eventually)

Please suggest some solutions, or at least give me words I can search on.

Comment: Microcontroller?

Comment: Nope. These subcircuits are powered before mcu is supplied.

Comment: CD4060 and some CD4000 series logic gates - power drain will be very low.

Comment: No, don't use some existing microcontroller...add one to subcircuit A. The added MCU turns on subcircuit B after 10 seconds then turns both off 2 seconds later. One microcontroller may be cheaper and smaller than a handful of timers.